# JSON Get some data in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have this json

```
"data": [
  {
     "name": "Jual beli hp cod tanjungsari, jatinangor, sumedang, dan sekitarnya",
     "id": "219307605068804",
     "privacy": "OPEN",
     "members": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "Andri We Lahk",
              "id": "100026036232248",
              "administrator": false
           }
        ],
        "paging": {
           "cursors": {
              "before": "QVFIUmJHeWstN",
              "after": "QVFIUmJHeWstN1Rna0RnYThZA"
           },
           "next": "https://graph"
        },
        "summary": {
           "total_count": 21424
        }
     }
  }
```

i can get the 'name' data by using this code using newtonsoft

```
JObject results = JObject.Parse(json);
            foreach (var result in results["data"])
            {
                 string name_dt = (string)result["name"];
            }
```

but how i can get the total_count data in c#?

thanks guys

Comment: same as like you access name from data same thing apply to total_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
 string name_dt = (string)result["name"];
```

you need

```
string name_dt = (string)result["members"]["summary"]["total_count"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would create classes that represent this JSON data.
For it you can use [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com).

Once you have your data, you can use the JsonConvert.Deserialize method to deserialize you Json into an instance of T, where T would be the "root" class.

A basic approach would be:

```
public class Datum2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Administrator { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string Before { get; set; }
    public string After { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}

public class Summary
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

public class Members
{
    public List<Datum2> Data { get; set; }
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
    public Summary Summary { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Privacy { get; set; }
    public Members Members { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then use

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)
```

Now you can access total_counts. For ex.:

```
jsonObject.data.First().Members.First().Summary.TotalCount.
```

Since I don't really know, what does represent this JSON, I just used the generated names for classes and props.